# Return last name, first name of author & how many books written greater than 1

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Two tables are book_data & author_data.

- `book_data` has 3 fields = `author_id`, `book_name`, `book_id`.
- `author_data` has 5 fields = `author_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `dob`, `social`.

I can run without the COUNT or HAVING:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, book_data.author_id
FROM author_data INNER JOIN book_data
                 ON book_data.author_id = author_data.author_id
                 WHERE book_data.author_id = author_data.author_id;
```

When I add:

```
GROUP BY author_id
HAVING COUNT (author_id) > 1)
```

I get error messages.

Comment: Add first_name and last_name to the GROUP BY clause, too.

Comment: Can you show us the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things: {1} when you are using JOIN and ON, you don't need to write a WHERE clause for joining the tables. {2} GROUP BY returns "... a single row of summary information for each group " (see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702))

Test setup (Oracle 12c)

```
create table authors (
  author_id  number primary key
, first_name varchar2(64)
, last_name  varchar2(64)
, dob        date
, social     varchar2(4000) 
);

create table books (
  author_id references authors
, book_name  varchar2(256)
, book_id    number generated always as identity start with 5000
);

begin
  insert into authors ( author_id, first_name, last_name, dob, social )
    values ( 1, 'fname1', 'lname1', date'2001-01-01', 'social1') ;
  insert into authors ( author_id, first_name, last_name, dob, social )
    values ( 2, 'fname2', 'lname2', date'2002-02-02', 'social2') ;
  insert into authors ( author_id, first_name, last_name, dob, social )
    values ( 3, 'fname3', 'lname3', date'2003-03-03', 'social3') ;
end ;
/

begin
  insert into books ( author_id, book_name ) values ( 1, 'book1' );
  insert into books ( author_id, book_name ) values ( 2, 'book2' );
  insert into books ( author_id, book_name ) values ( 2, 'book22' );
  insert into books ( author_id, book_name ) values ( 3, 'book3' );
  insert into books ( author_id, book_name ) values ( 3, 'book33' );
  insert into books ( author_id, book_name ) values ( 3, 'book333' );
end;
/
```

We now have the following authors and books:

```
SQL> select * from authors;
AUTHOR_ID  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME  DOB        SOCIAL   
1          fname1      lname1     01-JAN-01  social1  
2          fname2      lname2     02-FEB-02  social2  
3          fname3      lname3     03-MAR-03  social3  


SQL> select * from books;
AUTHOR_ID  BOOK_NAME  BOOK_ID  
1          book1      5000     
2          book2      5001     
2          book22     5002     
3          book3      5003     
3          book33     5004     
3          book333    5005
```

{1} Use JOIN ... ON (no WHERE clause)

```
SQL> select 
  2    first_name
  3  , last_name
  4  , B.author_id
  5  from authors A
  6    join books B on B.author_id = A.author_id ;

FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME  AUTHOR_ID  
fname1      lname1     1          
fname2      lname2     2          
fname2      lname2     2          
fname3      lname3     3          
fname3      lname3     3          
fname3      lname3     3
```

{2} Add GROUP BY and HAVING to the query.

```
select 
  first_name
, last_name
, B.author_id
from authors A
  join books B on B.author_id = A.author_id 
group by B.author_id
having count( B.author_id ) > 1
;
-- ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

-- works: SELECTed columns are listed in the GROUP BY clause
SQL> select 
  2    first_name
  3  , last_name
  4  , B.author_id
  5  from authors A
  6    join books B on B.author_id = A.author_id 
  7  group by B.author_id, first_name, last_name
  8  having count( B.author_id ) > 1
  9  ;

FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME  AUTHOR_ID  
fname2      lname2     2          
fname3      lname3     3
```

Comment: Thank you. That was a beautiful explanation. I have been a long time lurker on stackoverflow, but this was my first question. I appreciate your help.